# MySQL constantly shuts down (WordPress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've setup my AWS with the Amazon Linux. (t2.micro)
I'm running a fairly small WordPress site on it, which so far has worked out fine. (1k daily hits max)

The past couple weeks, the website went down a couple times every other week because the database just shuts down. Restarting usually has helped for another couple weeks.

It now started to happen more frequently and I'm trying to find a
solution. I'm new to everything AWS, and I can't seem to figure
out what the problem is. I attached the recent log.
Essentially, the DB is down every other minute now, restarting
doesn't help anymore.

My guess: t2.micro might be too small for what I'm doing?
I've already tried a lot of different hacks such as increasing
DB buffer size, restarting EC2 etc.

Here is my recent error log:

http://f.cl.ly/items/0H2m0y2a2n1H1w3U241k/Image%202016-06-11%20at%2010.56.57%20AM.png

Comment: What do the CPU credits look like when the database crashes? Memory usage? IOPS?

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. Is there an easy way for me to look up what you are asking for? Thank you! (i'm fairly new to AWS etc.)

Comment: Since it crashed about 10x in the last hour (after I restarted it every time) this seems to be the CPU activity: http://f.cl.ly/items/3t3L1h21410O2Y1Z3K1Q/Screen%20Shot%202016-06-11%20at%2012.19.27%20PM.png

Comment: CPU Credits will be in the same area as the CPU Utilization chart you just posted. IOPS will also be in there, in two charts (read and write). Memory usage will be easiest to view by logging into the server over ssh and running something like `top`.

Comment: Why don't you just scale up to a t2.small and see if there problem resolves itself. I'd think a micro isn't enough for a WordPress site

Comment: You say 1K hits per day so T2Micro is definitely not the correct solution either scale up the instance or use AWS RDS as the MYSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let everyone know that I have fixed my issue. At least, for now. Two things I did to make it stop:

1. Scaled up to t2.small
2. Created swap file for the DB.

   Thanks for your help and hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Yeah, you hit the memory limit, and the Linux OOM killer picked MySQL to kill to free up RAM.